# Connect to SQL Server without username and password using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server (SQL Developer 2017) with SQLAlchemy without using a username, password.

```py
from config import msql_serverName, msql_dbName
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

#1st attempt connection_string = f'{msql_serverName}/{msql_dbName}?trusted_connection=yes'

#2nd attempt connection_string = f'{msql_serverName}/{msql_dbName}?Trusted_Connection=yes?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server'

connection_string = f'{msql_serverName}/{msql_dbName}?Trusted_Connection=yes?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server&authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated'

engine = create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc://{connection_string}')

connection = engine.connect()

Part1_df.to_sql(name='RepresentationTable1', con=engine, if_exists='append',index=False)

connection.close()
```

Comment: Still getting an error with that:
ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]String or binary data would be truncated in table 'representation_v1.dbo.RepresentationTable1', column 'Country'. Truncated value: '\xa0'. (2628) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. (3621)")
[SQL: INSERT INTO [RepresentationTable1] ([Country], [countryCode], [Population], [LHR], [UHR], [CPRLH], [CPRUH], [Groups]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)].......

Comment: Yes, but that's a different question than the question above. Please accept the duplicate and search for an answer for the new problem or ask a new question for this problem!